# What is this IC marked IA89G or 1A89G?

Tags: integrated-circuit, packages

Please I need a bit of your help. Do you know what IC is this marked IA89G or 1A89G perhaps? I've tried Googling but to no avail. I'm really wondering why this is such a hard nut to crack.

Here are a few snapshots of the IC:

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Thanks a lot!

Joemill

Comment: Picture?  Pin count?  Package type?  Found where?

Comment: It would help if you posted the picture to give all the details.

Comment: As you do not yet have sufficient reputation to post images on this site, please upload a photo to any public image sharing site, and share the link in a comment... Someone with edit privileges will edit the image into your question.

Comment: Take a look at the answers in this similar question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34633/31woc-on-a-boost-converter-but-what-datasheet-goes-with-it

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is to describe the circuit a bit more, give us some more information to work with and some more pictures (that are in focus).

Comment: this is actually used for our LCD tester. the manufacturer of the test jig doesn't want to give us the schematic. :)

Comment: we suspect it's just a regulator while the reference designator is CAT37.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much as it might look like the CAT37 label on the PCB means "CAT component 37", it appears that it's actually an LED driver boost converter:

http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=CAT37

And FWIW, this converter looks like it's intended to power 4 white LEDs, so perhaps your tester equipment has a display with white backlight, or is able to test the backlights of LCDs under test?

Comment: believe this makes sense, gwideman! however, this is a 5-pin IC, mine is a 6-pin. but, now i know, this is definitely for the LCD display. thanks a lot, sir!

Comment: Sometimes a chip will have an extra pin that does nothing so that the product can be manufactured in a standard package. Sometimes an additional pin is used to provide some additional heat conduction.  For example, here is the similar (maybe equivalent) LT1937: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1937f.pdf  which comes in either 5 pin or 6 pin package, where the 6 pin version has an extra ground pin.

Comment: You can checkmark this as the answer if you like :-)